# Catch the Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed error in rescue

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to catch the error Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed in rescue block in chef ? I would like to catch this and give retry

Comment: Is this from an `execute` resource or something else?

Comment: @coderanger Yes it is execute. Inside execute there is a command.

Answer (score 2):

All resources (including `execute`) support a `retries` property where you can give it a number of times to retry the action.

Comment: Here's [a link to the chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/#resources-common-properties) as well for more information.